# How to get a data table from website with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to get table data from some website. Which best way to retrieve that data if I use javascript ?

Thanks before

Comment: do you know any server side languages like PHP? cause its better to use them.

Comment: oh PHP, i see, let me try

Comment: why recommend PHP? There are a TON of much better and easier to learn languages than THAT

Comment: FYI: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/web-scraping-with-node-js/ That tutorial uses JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

you cant not use JavaScript because you cannot make cross domain requests with it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use PHP, you can use "**http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net**" library so you can analyse the html from any website. this library is very easy to use and very helpfull.